# Xamarin Android change Manifest to allowBackup=true at runtime

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In my Xamarin Android app I have set the following in the Manifest:

```
<application android:allowBackup="false" />
```

I had to do this cause everytime I was installing the app, it kept track of the previous image of the sqlite database when some information was stored. A
fter adding that line to the Manifest, everytime I reinstall the app I have a clean database to work with, so no previous info is getting used.

But this creates another issue. I have a button on my app that simply creates a copy of the local database to the external storage. 
This copy works fine if I don't set up the allowBackup="false" in the Manifest, but since I have to (for the problem I mentioned earlier), I find myself in the 
impossibility to have both things working (i.e. the clean DB after each installation and the possibility to create copies of the DB to external drive).

I think that a possible workaround could be to keep the allowBackup="false" in the Manifest but change it to "true" just before creating a copy of the database. 
I can then change the flag back to "false".

But how can I achieve this? I haven't found anything online on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the manifest is that it can't be changed. For example this is where you declare on what your app will have access to (until Android Marshmallow this was the only way to make such a declaration). Obviously such things cannot change at the runtime.

Also the purpose of the backup is to restore in all cases including the one that you don't like (for whatever reason which is still not clear as I don't see why your app cannot continue to work with the data it had worked properly before the app was uninstalled), so basically you don't want the backup and you should set it to false.

Comment: I prefer that a fresh new installation will come with a clean database, hence I want the default behaviour to have allowBackup="false". But I need a workaround to be able to save a copy of a given database to an external storage.

Comment: @opt in Android world that description is being read like “I don’t want the backup”.  Of course it is legitimate to ask and to wait for further answers.

Comment: True that, but I also need to be able to make a local copy to external folder. This 2 requirements seems to be in conflict and hence I am asking for help, in case anyone has an idea.